# When is ok to repost a question on linux.SE?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Ok, so I have been going back and forth on questions between askubuntu.SE and linux.SE.  I don't mean to compare, but experience is telling me that I tend to get a better response rate on linux.SE.  A few of the question I have asked here still remains dead (even answered my own questsion), while all the questions on linux.SE have seen some sort of response.

Now, understanding that not all questions are equal, I still can't help feeling compelled reposting questions asked here and posting them on Linux.SE. I also understand that is kind of behaviour is not welcomed.  But, how do I deal with my shameless need for answer as opposed to my desire to be be a good citizen on SE?

Comment: There's not many edits to your questions, more detail and information bumps your question; if you want more attention on your question keep adding information to it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like what you really want is to *move* some of your unanswered questions from here to Unix.SE.

If that's the case, why not just delete those particular questions of yours here, and then post them on Unix.SE?

It's not cross-posting if the question is only one one site at a time, and:

- Since the questions you'd prefer to have on Unix.SE haven't gotten any response here, there's little harm done by deleting them. It's not like there are valuable answers that will be deleted too.
- Since you're subsequently posting the question on Unix.SE, it's not like people searching  the web to see if anyone has asked a question won't find just as useful information.

As for publicizing questions between AskUbuntu and Unix.SE:

- There is a feed in Ask Ubuntu's main chat room that notifies about questions that are posted on Unix.SE and tagged `ubuntu`.
- If you have an Ubuntu-related question on Unix.SE and you want to advertise it in Ask Ubuntu's main chat yourself, that would probably be OK, provided that

  - it's done in moderation
  - you don't just post the question link, but also provide some info in chat about why you need help
  - you stick around in chat so that if people want to reply in chat, they can
- If you have an Ubuntu-related question on Ask Ubuntu and you want to advertise it in Unix.SE's main chat, they might be OK with that. But I'm not active enough on Unix.SE to know for sure. I'd suggest posting a question on Unix.SE Meta first, to ask if this is OK.

Comment: That was very helpful!  Thank you.